# Java JCE cannot authenticate provider BC in jarsplice created jar

Tags: java, securityexception

I am working on a game and I am using the Slick2D library. I am also using bouncycastle for encryption. Then I use jarsplice to package everything together in a nice executable. And it runs fine until it needs to encrypt something. It gives me a `java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC` And I am using a signed jarfile (http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-150.jar)

Here is the stack trace

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:642)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:580)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.networking.ZenerithLogin.encryptLogin(ZenerithLogin.java:159)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.networking.ZenerithLogin.<init>(ZenerithLogin.java:112)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.MultiplayerMenu$1.performAction(MultiplayerMenu.java:90)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.gui.menu.MenuGameState.clickButton(MenuGameState.java:83)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.gui.menu.MenuGameState.checkForButtonClicks(MenuGameState.java:75)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.gui.menu.MenuGameState.update(MenuGameState.java:51)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.gui.menu.AbstractGameState.update(AbstractGameState.java:47)
    at org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame.update(StateBasedGame.java:266)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
    at net.matrixstudios.zenerith.gui.Window.<init>(Window.java:28)
    at net.matrixstudios.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: file:/C:/Users/M4trixSh4d0w/Desktop/Zenerith_Alpha.0.2.1.5.jar has unsigned entries - org/bouncycastle/LICENSE.class
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:462)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:322)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:250)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:161)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:187)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:638)
    ... 14 more
```

So how do I authenticate the jarfile to run?
This is a standalone executable jarfile.

Comment: try adding following line to the java.security file security.provider.9=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Comment: will that make it work on other people's computers? Or just mine? I'm trying to make a release jarfile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably want to register the cryptographic service provider at runtime to ensure the configuration will work for everyone. You can use either of the Security.addProvider() or Security.insertProviderAt() methods. See documentation linked below under "Managing Providers".

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Provider

Just use addProvider() unless the order of providers is somehow important for you. I saw one contributor commented that you might slot it in at entry #9, but I didn't see evidence that this is right for your configuration, so probably just an extraneous detail from his/her config file. Obviously, if I missed something about your configuration and you do need it there, then go for insertProviderAt().

Comment: I already have    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

Comment: Got a closer look at your stack trace. It says your jar has unsigned entries. Thinking you'll need to sign the executable jar as well.

Comment: I signed it, but now it gives me a untrusted signer error

Comment: Would try..jarsigner -verify jar-file

Comment: See "ensuring signers are trusted" here.. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html#JCEAuthTrust

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Android developer, got this error when I upgraded the compile and build tool to Android 12 (31), I tried lots of ways to fix it and finally I found the only way that works is changing the JDK to the version of 11.0.14.1 (x86_64), I worked on Mac M1, the downloading link of this version is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html